# Analytical form for noisily-observed Brownian motion

Tags: likelihood, gaussian-process, kalman-filter

- Let $0 < t_1 < t_2 < \ldots < t_N$ be given.
- Let $\{ B_t \}_{t \geqslant 0}$ be a one-dimensional Brownian motion, started at $B_0 = 0$.

Suppose that for $i = 1, \ldots, N$, we observe $Y_i \sim \mathcal{N} \left( B_{t_i}, \sigma^2 \right)$, where the noise is independent across observations.

**I would like** an analytical form for the marginal likelihood

\begin{align}
P \left( \{ Y_i \}_{i = 1}^N \right) = \int \left\{P \left( \{ B_{t_i} \}_{i = 1}^N \right) \prod_{i = 1}^N P ( Y_i | B_{t_i} ) \right\} \, dB_{t_1} dB_{t_2} \cdots dB_{t_N}.
\end{align}

Given that everything in sight is linear and Gaussian, it would be possible to evaluate this numerically using e.g. a Kalman filter. For my purposes, this is insufficient: I am interested in knowing how $P(Y)$ varies as $\sigma^2$ and the $\{ t_i \}_{i=1}^N$ change. As such, it is of particular interest for me to have an analytical form for this expression.

Comment: What you really have is just a Gaussian AR(1), for which likelihood expression is a standard calculation.

Comment: @Michael Ah, right - because the $\{ Y_i \}$ form a(n inhomogeneous) Markov chain, I can just work out the transition densities for those, and throw them together. I'll have a go at this, thanks.